# Difficult Apache URL rewriting

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to rewrite this URL :

`myhost.com/elecresult-Cantonales-2011/039/03915.html`

to this one :

`myhost.com/elecresult-Cantonales-2011/(path)/039%2F03915.html`

Could you help me with the rewrite rule ? Is it possible to urlencode ?

Comment: how far have you got so far? What works/what not?

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions in your RewriteRule to match the path you've laid out.

If you want to match a generic path i.e. /first/second/third you can use this regular expression: ^/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)$. You use the notation $n (where n is 1 - 10) to match the corresponding captures.  To change this to /first//secondthird, you specify the replacement string:
$1//$2$3

The below snippet should do that.  You can add it to your virtual host directive, your .htaccess file, or to the httpd.conf within the directory directive.

[L] specifies to write this rule and stop.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite>
   RewriteEngine on

   RewriteRule ^/(.+)/([0-9]+)/(.+)$ $1/(path)/$2%2F$3 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm gonna try it.

How can I match URLs with 'elecresult-' pattern ?